# XCode: 'pod init' failing with ruby json "incompatible library version" error

Tags: ios, json, ruby, xcode

I created a new XCode project and ran `pod init` at where that project exitsts. I got the following error.

```
/Users/xxx/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/json-2.0.2/lib/json/ext/parser.bundle (fatal)
```

I didn't make any modification to my project. Where is the error coming from? It seems like it's coming from ruby, but it's weird to have a ruby error on a XCode project. Does anyone know how to solve this?
Thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems like an issue with your Cocoapods installation, try [uninstalling](https://superuser.com/questions/686317/how-to-fully-uninstall-the-cocoapods-from-the-mac-machine) and reinstalling it.

#### Uninstalling

```
gem uninstall cocoapods
gem uninstall cocoapods-core
gem uninstall cocoapods-downloader
```

#### Reinstalling

```
gem install cocoapods
```